# Codeigniter active record query works differently from custom query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, count

Code igniter active record query:

```
$this->blog_db->select('a.tytul, a.data_dodania, b.post_id, COUNT(b.post_id) as liczba')
                       ->from('posts a')
                       ->join('komentarze b', 'a.id=b.post_id')
                       ->group_by('b.post_id')
                       ->order_by('liczba', 'desc')
                       ->limit(5)
                       ->get('posts');
```

It gives me result of count query multiplyed by number of posts but it should work like this:
[custom mysql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4t02.png)
Using the same query as custom query in codeigniter works like a charm

```
$this->blog_db->query('SELECT a.tytul, b.post_id, a.data_dodania, COUNT(b.post_id) as liczba
                                    FROM posts a
                                    JOIN komentarze b ON a.id=b.post_id
                                    GROUP BY b.post_id
                                    ORDER BY liczba desc
                                    LIMIT 0, 5
                                    ');
```

What I have did wrong on active record query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `->get();` since you included `->from('posts a')` already.

> The FROM portion of your query can be specified in the `$this->db->get()` function, so use whichever method you prefer.